# Action listener and action event

Tags: java, swing, events, awt, action

Can any one explain for me why do we pass `item1`, `2`, `3` and `passwordField` to another class (the handler) through an object? And what is `getsource`? And get command? And why do we create a string here?

```
thehandler handler =new thehandler();

item1.addActionListener(handler);
item2.addActionListener(handler);
item3.addActionListener(handler);
passwordField.addActionListener(handler);
```

### thehandler

```
private class thehandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        String string="";

    if(event.getSource()==item1)
        string=String.format("field 1: %s",event.getActionCommand());
    else if(event.getSource()==item2)
        string=String.format("field 2: %s",event.getActionCommand());
    else if(event.getSource()==item3)
        string=String.format("field 3: %s",event.getActionCommand());
    else if (event.getSource()==passwordField)
        string=String.format("passwordField: %s",event.getActionCommand());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by having a read through [the Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the solution can be obtained by proper research of the Observer Pattern and How to use ActionListeners tutorial

Answer (score 1):

> can any one explain for me why do we pass item1,2,3 and passwrodFiled to another class(the handler)through an object

This is rather vague, but basically, what this allows you to do is plugin functionality that can deal with contextual requirements.  That is, you don't need to extend and override methods of these classes to change their behaviour, you can simply provide a callback which can be used instead.

> and what is getsource and get command and why do we creat a string here ?

The `getSource` method returns the `Object` reference which created this event, this is useful, as shown in your example, where you are expecting more then more source for the event trigger.

The `getActionCommand` method returns an associated `String` which represents a possible "command".  The core reason for this is, you may not have a reference to the original object which created the event and/or you may have multiple different objects who are creating the `ActionEvent`, but want to trigger the same flow of logic.

The `actionPerformed` method in your example is creating a `String` message which is displayed by the `JOptionPane`

Comment: firstly thank you for your asnwer ,

Comment: second u mean that Object is a call back from class B to class A so that we can use all methods in class B at A ? and we must always make methods with name actionPerformed or it's up to me ,,finlly what is (ActionEvent event) is Obhject ? or what ? sorry for spam

Comment: All classes in Java extend from Object. ActionEvent extends from EventObject which events from Object. A notifies B (A been the textfield, for example and B been the handler), but you can access A via the ActionListener's getSource method